# Hosting SPA on subfolder with Nginx

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

I have a React app that's hosted in the same domain of my website under `/app`. Every path, except `/app` is handled by another server. I'm packing the app to be deployed in an `app` folder on my server too, with the hope of making it work properly. I'm not sure if it's actually necessary. I did it because it works fine on Apache.

I have a `nginx.conf` that works just fine when I host the app in the root of the domain. But I'm having a hard time figuring out what I have to change to make it work in the `/app` path.

I have already tried changing the root to the `app` folder in my server, but it doesn't work. Creating another `location` for `/app` and it doesn't work either. What else Could I try changing to get it working? Here's my current file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        error_page   400 401 403 404 /app/index.html;
        error_page   500 502 503 504 /app/index.html;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WEB HOST**

Use the `proxy_path` directive to route to the target server as required. If using the same host for all web resources then just do this:

```
server_name www.example.com;
location / {
  proxy_pass http://mywebserver/
}
```

A different target location could be used for the `/app` path, or it could point to files on the nginx server:

```
location ^~ / {
  proxy_pass http://mywebserver1/
}
location ^~ /app/ {
  proxy_pass http://mywebserver2/app/
}
```

I'd recommend using a physical path for the React app that matches the end user's browser path.

**APPLICATION**

When the user browses to the `/app` path it will hit the React SPA. The index.html file can be deployed with a [base element](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/index.html) like this, so that resources use this path as a prefix, to match the locations of deployed files:

```html
<base href='/app/' />
```

If you are using the React router, you can give it a [base path](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/index.tsx) that uses the value from the HTML file:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={BasePath.get()}>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

The code within the SPA can then be written independently of the deployed path. For example, this code will navigate to `/app/mypath`:

```js
navigate('/mypath');
```

**SUMMARY**

This type of micro UI deployment tends to require both web host and application configuration. You can maybe use my example app in the above links as something to compare against.